# sql query to get the value of a second table once

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Not sure if this can be done with how this is designed. Im trying to get the customer name from the products table to return to the Invoices table, so I can sum the totals, grouped by customer name. the invoice table has one unique document id and id. I need the name for each invoice. The products table has many records with the customer name (one for each line item on the invoice).

I have a sqlite database (orders.sqlite) with two table:

- Invoices: id, document_id, total, date_created, date_modified
- Products: id, invoice_id, customer_name, created_at, updated_at

I need to get the total amount of all invoices for each customer. The tables look like this:

`Invoices
ID | DOCUMENT_ID | TOTAL  | CREATED_AT          | UPDATED_AT
25 | 17220       | 0.01   | 2016-08-06 23:13:43 | 2016-08-06 23:13:43
26 | 17214       | 12.95  | 2016-08-06 23:23:23 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23
27 | 17215       | 665.25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23
28 | 17216       | 445.20 | 2016-08-06 23:23:24 | 2016-08-06 23:23:24
29 | 17217       | 250.80 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25
30 | 17225       | 250.80 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25`

`Products
ID  | INVOICE_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | CREATED_AT          | UPDATED_AT
93  | 25         | customer1     | 2016-08-06 23:13:43 | 2016-08-06 23:13:43
94  | 26         | customer2     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
95  | 27         | customer3     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
96  | 27         | customer3     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
97  | 27         | customer3     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
98  | 27         | customer3     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
99  | 28         | customer4     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
100 | 28         | customer4     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
101 | 28         | customer4     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
102 | 29         | customer4     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27
102 | 30         | customer3     | 2016-08-06 23:23:27 | 2016-08-06 23:23:27`

Im trying to find the customer name for each invoice and then, sum the invoice totals.

`ID | DOCUMENT_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME  | TOTAL  | CREATED_AT          | UPDATED_AT
25 | 17220       | custom1        | 0.01   | 2016-08-06 23:13:43 | 2016-08-06 23:13:43
26 | 17214       | custom2        | 12.95  | 2016-08-06 23:23:23 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23
27 | 17215       | custom3        | 665.25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23 | 2016-08-06 23:23:23
28 | 17216       | custom4        | 445.20 | 2016-08-06 23:23:24 | 2016-08-06 23:23:24
29 | 17217       | custom4        | 250.80 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25
30 | 17225       | custom3        | 250.80 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25 | 2016-08-06 23:23:25`

The final step is to sum all the invoices for each customer. So the final results Im looking for, would be something like this (adding the totals for matching customers).

`CUSTOMER_NAME  |TOTAL
custom1        | 0.01
custom2        | 12.95
custom3        | 916.05
custom4        | 696.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT t1.CUSTOMER_NAME,
       SUM(COALESCE(t2.TOTAL, 0)) AS TOTAL
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT INVOICE_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME
    FROM Products
) t1
LEFT JOIN Invoices t2
    ON t1.INVOICE_ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.CUSTOMER_NAME
ORDER BY t1.CUSTOMER_NAME
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, first result set

```
SELECT max(i.id) id, 
i.document_id document_id, 
p.customer_name, 
SUM(i.total) total, 
MAX(i.created_at) created_at, 
MAX(i.updated_at) updated_at 
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN products p ON p.invoice_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.document_id, p.customer_name
ORDER BY max(i.id)
```

Fort Second result set:

```
SELECT p.customer_name, SUM(i.total) total
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT invoice_id, 
            customer_name FROM products) p ON p.invoice_id = i.id
GROUP BY p.customer_name
```